# how to use multiple sum and group by in subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

[ER DIAGRAM SNAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OavT4.png)    have to Find the Order Amount Total   for 2 type of orders for each year.
table is SalesOrderHeader
Subtotal +  TaxAmt  gives the total order amount
OnlineOrderFlag(0/1 is direct/online respectively)

1>Display the results in the below formats

```
OrderYear         Direct              Online

2001                 75423               344344

2002            
2003        
2004
```

SQL:

```
select year(a.OrderDate),

( select  SUM(SubTotal+TaxAmt) FROM SalesOrderHeader b  WHERE OnlineOrderFlag = 0 group by year(b.OrderDate) ) as tot  ,

( select SUM(SubTotal+TaxAmt) FROM SalesOrderHeader c WHERE OnlineOrderFlag = 1 group by year(c.OrderDate) ) as tt

FROM SalesOrderHeader a inner join  SalesOrderHeader b 
on b.SalesOrderID = a.SalesOrderID
            inner join
   SalesOrderHeader c on c.SalesOrderID = a.SalesOrderID
```

can someone please tel how to proceed further? i'm stuck at this

2> and also how to find it in the below format ?

```
OnlineFlag               Year                    TotalAmt
Direct                   2001    
Direct                   2002    
Direct                   2003    
Direct                   2004    
Online                   2001    
Online                   2002    
Online                   2003    
Online                   2004
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Added the inner subquery to make it clear where the group by needs to go and to add the subtotal and tax for each record before summarizing.

```
select a.year
      ,SUM(Case when a.OnlineOrderFlag = 1 THEN a.total else null end) as Direct
      ,SUM(Case when a.OnlineOrderFlag = 0 THEN a.total else null end) as Online
FROM (select year(OrderDate) as year, (SubTotal+TaxAmt) as total, OnlineOrderFlag
      from SalesOrderHeader) a
Group by a.year
```

Comment: Nope, its showing the following errorError Code : 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(ORDERDATE), ONLINEORDERFLAG,
        SUM(SUBTOTAL) SUBTOTAL,SUM(TAXAMT) TAXAMT,
        SUM(SUBTOTAL + TAXAMT) TOTALDUE
FROM SALESORDERHEADER
WHERE ONLINEORDERFLAG = 1
GROUP BY YEAR(ORDERDATE) WITH ROLLUP
UNION
SELECT YEAR(ORDERDATE), ONLINEORDERFLAG,
        SUM(SUBTOTAL) ,SUM(TAXAMT),
        SUM(SUBTOTAL + TAXAMT)
FROM SALESORDERHEADER
WHERE ONLINEORDERFLAG = 0
GROUP BY YEAR(ORDERDATE) WITH ROLLUP
;
```

Comment: with a little modifications with the spelling this works fine for the second question.